# How to dismiss a Dialog in Android by clicking it inside?

Tags: android, dialog, listener, dismiss

I have seen several posts on how to dismiss a dialog by clicking on the outside. But is there a way to get the same functionality by clicking the inside the dialog window?

Are there any listeners for the Dialog that would detect a tap on the Dialog Window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overriding [`Dialog.onTouchEvent(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) catches any tap, anywhere on the screen. To dismiss the dialog by tapping anywhere:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this) {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Tap anywhere to close dialog.
    this.dismiss();
    return true;
  }
};
```

This snippet nullifies the need to call [`dialogObject.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to detect a touch event anywhere within the bounds of a dialog. If you're creating a custom dialog (i.e. by assembling a set of `View`s into a layout `View` of some sort, and then setting the parent `View` as the dialog's main content view using `.setContentView()`) then perhaps you could simply set an `onTouch` listener to that content parent `View`. Furthermore, you could grab hold of views using `mDialog.findViewById()`, so if for example you were using an `AlertDialog`, perhaps you could determine somehow what resource ID to use to grab hold of its main layout `View`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Layout in your Dialog, you could get a reference to that as view, and put a onClickListener on that.  So assuming your dialog has a custom layout, and view for the entire dialog, get a reference to that.

For instance, assuming a dialog has a LinearLayout named mainll, that contains your custom views, you would:

```
LinearLayout ll - (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainll);
ll.setOnClickListener(...) { onClick()... }
```

Then anytime anything is clicked within the LinearLayout, it will register a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own Dialog activity and call finish() when the user clicks the area that you want to close your Dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to have the Dialog hover over my current activity (there is a transparent area over & beneath the Dialog from which my current activity is displayed). TO eloborate, the Dialog is displayed when a button in my activity is clicked. I'm able to dismiss the Dialog by tapping on the region outside the Dialog using 

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

According to the reks, I can't use any buttons on the Dialog! Hence, I'm trying to search for a way that would dismiss the Dialog when it is clicked.

Comment: You can use any layout you want with an activity; including one that is transparent. It will look just like a dialog box and you can make it behave any way that you want. If you really want something that looks and behaves like a modal dialog box but with custom dismiss logic, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which explains how to handle onTouch events within the dialog. The trick is in creating a custom listener.

http://about-android.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

```
here i have taken my close icon ,if u need u can take anything like button

first of all u have implement to the class

class somethingclass Dialog implements View.OnClickListener

then set the event for particular 

      icon_close.setOnClickListener(this);

then override the class function

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(R.id.icon_close==v.getId()){
            dismiss();
        }else
}


Note:  if passible u can give dilaog.dismiss();
```